# How to verify id token for Line-api? (how to use jwt.net in the same way as java?)

Tags: c#, .net, jwt

How to verify id_token use JWT.Net?
This is the code in java:

```
            JWT.require(
            Algorithm.HMAC256(channelSecret))
            .withIssuer("https://access.line.me")
            .withAudience(channelId)
            .withClaim("nonce", nonce)
            .build()
            .verify(id_token);
```

Details on https://developers.line.me/en/docs/line-login/web/integrate-line-login/
See Parts:`Decoding and validating ID tokens`

How to make the same function in C#.Net?
There is JWT.Net on nuget didn't found similar method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to use the JWT.Net now.

```
                decodedJson = new JwtBuilder()
                .WithSecret(secret)
                .WithAlgorithm(hmacsha256Algorithm)
                .MustVerifySignature()
                .Decode(idToken);
```